# When Lambda query Use ‘Contains’ and it does not match the condition “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” error returns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, lambda

Platform C#, Dot net 4.0

```
var city0 = DataCache.GetAllCities().Where(c => c.GeoName.Contains("Dubai")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The Variable **Duabi** exists in data and this returns city object

```
var city1 = DataCache.GetAllCities().Where(c => c.CityID== 23804982) .FirstOrDefault();
```

The id **23804982** is not exists in data and this returns null object

```
var city2 = DataCache.GetAllCities().Where(c => c.GeoName.Contains("WrongCityName")).FirstOrDefault();
```

The Variable **WrongCityName**  does not exists in data and this returns the following error.

*Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

[EDIT]
I got the error when the last query executed. Not when I evaluate city2

Comment: When do you get the error? Is it when you try to use `city2` or is it when the query is executed?

Comment: I got the error when the query executed. And the reason was GeoName contains null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `city2` will be null, because you've used `FirstOrDefault` - and the default value for classes is null.

You should check it for nullity before using it:

```
if (city2 != null)
{
    // Okay, I found a matching city. Now I can use it
}
```

Now that's assuming the code you've actually given is executing without any problems. It wouldn't if `c.GeoName` was null for some city... because you'd be calling `Contains` on a null reference. You can fix that with:

```
var city2 = DataCache.GetAllCities()
                     .Where(c => c.GeoName != null &&
                                 c.GeoName.Contains("WrongCityName"))
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have used the if (city2 != null) block. But it will not reach there. before that i got the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error message

Comment: @Jomy: See my edit. It's probably because you've got a city with no GeoName. Your first query would have the same problem, but presumably Dubai comes earlier in the city sequence than the city with a null GeoName.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `c` or `c.GeoName` is null -- have you checked those?

Comment: Yes Lambert . That was the issue. Thanks